# How to add objects in a linkedlist JAVA?

Tags: java, linked-list

I want to store coordinates(xy integers) and another one integer. I have a class with the variables x,y, steps and another one class in which I want to make objects of the other class and store them in a linkedlist but this only works when I create the objects inside a for loop. When I create objects with the same name compiler says "variable already defined in method main".
How can i create objects outside for loop?

this is the one that works with the for loop

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    LinkedList<Coordinates> coords = new LinkedList<Coordinates>();
    for (int j=0; j<3;j++)
    {
        Coordinates xy = new Coordinates();
        System.out.println("give x");
        xy.x=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("give y");
        xy.y=sc.nextInt();
        xy.steps=xy.steps+1;
        coords.add(xy);          
    }    
  }
}
```

I want something like this but it doesn't work

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main 
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    LinkedList<Coordinates> coords = new LinkedList<Coordinates>();

    Coordinates xy = new Coordinates();
    System.out.println("give x");
    xy.x=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("give y");
    xy.y=sc.nextInt();
    xy.steps=xy.steps+1;
    coords.add(xy);

    Coordinates xy = new Coordinates();
    System.out.println("give x");
    xy.x=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("give y");
    xy.y=sc.nextInt();
    xy.steps=xy.steps+1;
    coords.add(xy);                 
 }
}
```

There will be another objects not only these two!

Comment: You need to post code and explain your problem better. It's very unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You've copy-pasted your declaration of `Coordinates xy`.

This is the cause of the "variable already defined" error message that you got.  The actual error message should even give you the line number of the problem so you can identify it.

Just reference it as `xy` in the second case.